# How to add Buttons to a Canvas

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I was wondering if it is possible to add [`Button`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) to a [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html). I am using a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) as the parent and I put the `Canvas` inside of it.

Comment: No, but you can use the `StackPane` to put the button on top of the `Canvas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No.

#### Why?

The method [`protected ObservableList<Node> getChildren()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) is part of the class [`Parent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html). [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) for example extends `Region` which extends `Parent` (which then extends `Node` (which can be added to the [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) returned by `getChildren(...)`)). So only sub classes of `Parent` can have children (if the implementing class makes `getChildren(...)` public).

A [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Canvas.html) on the other hand extends `Node` directly and therefore has no `getChildren(...)` method.

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Please also note that you can't generally assume that a class can't do X because it doesn't extend Y. The reasoning above relies on the assumption that you are working with a well designed library.</sub>

Comment: The first paragraph of the *Why?* section mostly contains flawed logic. According to this logic `Map` doesn't provide a `get` method since the get method is part of the `List` type... Just explain that `Canvas` does not allow for children without mentioning any other classes extending `Node`...

Comment: @fabian you are right in that this does not strictly follow logically. But as a developer you you make assumptions when working with a well designed library. When you work with an UI library where really everything is about nesting `Node`s in other `Node`s and there is a class called `Parent`, you would assume that anything that has children will be a `Parent`. Just like if a method is called `getIterator()` I will assume it returns an `Iterator<?>`, while this is not necessarily the case. But all of this would make the answer too long and complex.

Comment: @fabian I added a compact version of my reasoning at the bottom of my answer